# How to show/ hide windowActionBar programatically in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am applying one style to two activities. `MainActivity.java` has toolbar setup instead of action bar, therefore, I have following line in theme style to hide action bar:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

And in the another activity I have action bar enabled:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But this returns **NOException** error.

I tried following but didn't help either:

```
actionBar.show();
```

**Style:**

```
<style name="BrownTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/brown</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_brown</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@color/brown</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**Elaboration:**
I am using style for two activities. The first activity has it's own toolbar instead of default action bar and the second activity has action bar. If I remove from style then I cannot run the first activity and if I put, then I cannot run the second activity. I want to enable it programatically in second activity.

Is there any possibility to change the style item attributes programatically? or any override method to bypass what I have in style item attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this using custom toolbar for both activities.

The `style.xml` now has the following theme:

```
<style name="BrownTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/brown</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_brown</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@color/brown</item>
</style>
```

And in the second activity (or all other activities):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And the toolbar layout (app_bar_main.xml):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And the activity layout:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`getSupportActionBar().hide();` to hide

and `getSupportActionBar().show();` to show.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work in the second activity when it is hide in style.

Comment: I am using style for two activities. The first activity has it's own toolbar instead of default action bar and the second activity has action bar. If I remove from style then I cannot run the first activity and if I put, then I cannot run the second activity. I want to enable it programatically in second activity.

Comment: What happens when you set true in styles and hide/show in activity

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.revittechnology.mullahnasruddin/com.revittechnology.mullahnasruddin.About}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Well then, set the action bar for each activity separately in manifest donot use a common style, have separate styles for each activity, something like android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" inside of the activity tag in manifest